# C++ When template argument deduction fails

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

Why can't C++ determine that I intend to create a `unique_ptr<A>` with this syntax?  (a has previously been declared as `unique_ptr<A>`)

```
a = unique_ptr(new A());
```

It seems awfully redundant to have to include `<A>`.  This works for most functions templates I use, why not unique_ptr?

**EDIT:** C++ now supports make_unique, with no redundancy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is a *class* template, not a *function* template.  Argument deduction only happens for *function* templates, not *class* templates.

A commonly used trick is to write a function template that creates an object of the instantiated class template type, for example:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_ptr(T* ptr) 
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr);
}
```

For `std::unique_ptr`, though, I'd avoid doing this:  a `std::unique_ptr` object should directly take ownership of the dynamically allocated object, so there should not be a need for this.  Your code should either be written as:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
```

or, if `a` already exists, a call to `reset()` can be used:

```
a.reset(new A());
```

---

As for why type deduction won't work for instantiating a class template, consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    template <typename U> X(U) { }
};
```

There is no way that `T` could be deduced from an invocation of the constructor.  Even in "simpler" cases where there is a constructor with a parameter of type `T`, there can still be trouble since constructors can be overloaded.

Comment: LoL... I need to type fast. :D.. +1

Comment: excellent answer, just like make_pair I suppose.  Is there any language reason why template argument deduction can't occur for class templates?

Comment: @James: Bad Logic. The example you showed, or the cases you're talking about can be categorically rejected, labeling them "non-deduced" context. The question can then be asked : what about cases when template argument can be deduced such as when there is only one constructor whose parameter is T?

Comment: @Nawaz:  The cases I describe cover the vast majority of class templates, including `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @James: That is true. But template argument deduction doesn't happen even when it can be deduced. So your explanation renders nothing, in my opinion, as argument deduction doesn't occur even when there is no "trouble" due to overloaded constructors.

Comment: @Nawaz:  The feature doesn't exist.  If it did exist, it would only be usable in a very small number of cases, and it wouldn't enable anything particularly interesting, so the cost of adding the feature (added complexity to the argument deduction rules) isn't worth it.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @James: I would say it would have been useful almost to the same extent as it's useful in case of function argument deduction.