# Understanding a snippet of perfect forwarding & variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I've seen a snippet this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486631) and I can't seem to understand how the arrangement of templates and typenames create the final function call that is shown in main().

In particular, the arrangement of variadic template templates and the use of std::forward are confusing to me.

Can anybody break this snippet of code down so I can better understand it?

```
#include <utility>

template <template <typename...> class TemplateClass, typename... Args>
TemplateClass<Args...> make(Args&&... args)
{
    return TemplateClass<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() 
{
  make<std::pair>(1, 2);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001

Comment: If you remove all the `...` does it make more sense? Sometimes it is easier to understand these examples is to remove the "variadic" part and then add them back (they add detail to what needs to be expanded and where).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a function template with a template *template-parameter*:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class TT>
TT<int, double>
make(int i, double d)
{
    return TT<int, double>(i, d);
}
```

You specify a class or alias template which has two type parameters, and this function will use a specialization of this template, created using `int` and `double` as the template arguments. For example:

```
make< std::pair >(42, 4.2);
```

This returns a `std::pair<int, double>`.

---

We can now "templatize" the (function) arguments of this function:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class TT, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
TT<Arg0, Arg1>
make(Arg0 a0, Arg1 a1)
{
    return TT<A0, A1>(a0, a1);
}
```

The template parameters `Arg0` and `Arg1` are intended to be deduced from the types of the (function) arguments used to call the function:

```
int i = 42;
double d = 4.2;
make< std::pair >(i, d); // returns a `std::pair<int, double>`
```

---

For more complex data types, we might want to use perfect forwarding:

```
make< std::pair >( 42, std::vector<int>(1000) );
```

This returns a `std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>`.
The above definition of `make` will **move** the temporary vector created via `std::vector<int>(1000)` into the second function parameter. However, it will be **copied** from there into the object created via `TT<A0, A1>(a0, a1)`.

We can change the definition of `make` to implement perfect forwarding as follows:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class TT, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
TT<Arg0, Arg1>
make(Arg0&& a0, Arg1&& a1)
{
    return TT<A0, A1>(std::forward<A0>(a0), std::forward<A1>(a1));
}
```

The temporary vector created via `std::vector<int>(1000)` will be moved into the object created within the return-statement.

---

Now, we can generalize this function template to N arguments; the template *template-parameter* also has to be generalized so that you can pass any class or alias template that takes some number of type parameters.

```
template <template <typename...> class TemplateClass, typename... Args>
TemplateClass<Args...> make(Args&&... args)
{
    return TemplateClass<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Line by line breakdown of the code

```
template <template <typename...> class TemplateClass, typename... Args>
```

The `TemplateClass` is itself a template that requires a variable template argument. Without the variadic part, this could look like `template <typename> class TemplateClass` for a single argument, or `template <typename, typename> class TemplateClass` for two arguments. `Args` are the variadic template arguments to this function template `make`.

```
TemplateClass<Args...> make(Args&&... args)
```

The return is of type `TemplateClass<Args...>`, from the original template argument to the template function, and is defined using the variadic `Args` of the original template. `make` takes a variadic parameter pack called `args` by what is often called a "universal reference" (the `&&`, this may or may not eventually be a rvalue reference in this case).

```
{
    return TemplateClass<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

An object of the return type is created using a constructor that accepts all the argument originally provided to the function.

Perfecting forwarding is used to ensure that the value category is maintained for each argument originally received. The `...` expands what is to the left of it, so for each argument in the parameter pack, a `std::forward` is applied (which is what is required since `std::forward` only accepts a single argument.

#### How does [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/3747990) work?

In a nutshell, the combination of reference collapsing and a `static_cast`. Basically if the argument is a lvalue reference, the return type to the `std::forward` is also a lvalue reference. If it is an rvalue reference, then the return type is a rvalue reference (akin to the result of a `std::move`).

#### How do ["universal references"](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (or "forwarding references") work?

They power the mechanics of `std::forward` and similar functions, like the `make` in this case. Another example is the `std::make_shared` function in the standard library. They are so named because they can bind to "any" reference (both `&` and `&&`) because of the reference collapsing rules introduced in C++11.