# How does copy assignment work in for folly::Optional<T>?

Tags: c++, option-type, folly

I was reading the code in folly::Optional for [copy assignment](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Optional.h) and I am not clear how exactly the call to `construct()` assigns a value to the optional. Specifically in `construct()` how does this expression work?

```
new (const_cast<void*>(ptr)) Value(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: You've linked an internal FB page there. Probably want to find the external link?

Comment: It's using `placement new` on an existing memory location.

Comment: The link you gave is not for the copy constructor, and the code you quote isn't there, BTW.

Comment: You may be interested in: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at. Folly seemingly just provided its custom version for pre-C++20 code (which is basically all code now ;).

Comment: Edited the link to point to the external, openly available, version of  folly::Optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deconstruct the line you wrote:

`std::forward<Args>(args)...` is performing [variadic-template perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486432/variadic-template-templates-and-perfect-forwarding). In essence, it means that whatever was an r-value will be forwarded to, and so on, for any number of arguments.

`Value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is calling the constructor of `Value` on these arguments.

`new (const_cast<void*>(ptr))` ... is calling [placement new](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/).

So what the line is saying is, create an object at this specific memory location, constructing the object there by forwarding all the arguments you got.

Comment: I am a bit surprused by the lack of scope operator on the new.  I guess that is too paranoid for FB.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Interesting

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont In my experience, Facebook/Folly does not care much about portability and "corner cases". (For instance, its `PackedSyncPtr` works only on some listed architectures and simply triggers a compilation error on others.)